# Create Blank space When use renderpartial in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I use `@Html.RenderPartial` from View , Its Render Partial , but Its put some blank Sapce befor Partial Content , Whats Problem ?

[image]

and get inspect element ,contains All Layout view content like as script,link,footer ,...:

[image]

Comment: Right-click the blank space, click "Inspect Element".

Comment: @PsarTak, Post your view(razor) code too. And check the CSS for any margin or padding has been set or not

Comment: I mean _you_ need to analyze why this space is there, what part of CSS shows it.

Answer (score 0):

i think since RenderPartial writes to Response Directly you can use @Html.Partial to Get Html in place